# Show that every derivation of the non-abelian two-dimensional Lie algebra is inner

Tags: proof-verification, lie-algebras

For any $2$-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra $g$, there exists a basis $a,b$ such that $[a,b]=a$. Now I want to prove that any derivation of $L$ is inner. My proof: $D[x,y]=[Dx,y]+[x,Dy]= [k_1 a+k_2b,b]+[a,k_3a+k_4b]= k_1a+k_4a=ka$, for some $k\in F$.

Now, $ka=[a,kb]=ad_a(l)$, for some $l\in g$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You have shown that for every $x,y \in \mathfrak{g}$ there exists some $l \in \mathfrak{g}$ (I assume $L = \mathfrak{g}$) with $D([x,y]) = \mathrm{ad}_a(l)$. What you actually need to show is that there exists some $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ with $D(y) = \mathrm{ad}_x(y)$ for every $y \in \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Ok! are they more steps I have to do, or my approach is not necessary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that for every $x,y \in \mathfrak{g}$ there exists som $l \in \mathfrak{g}$ with $D[x,y] = \mathrm{ad}_a(l)$. What you need to show is that there exists some $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ with $D(y) = \mathrm{ad}_x(y)$ for every $y \in \mathfrak{g}$.

---

There is probably a short and elegant solution, but this should work too:

With respect to the basis $(a,b)$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ we have
$$
 \mathrm{ad}_a =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 \mathrm{ad}_b =
 \begin{pmatrix}
            -1 & 0 \\
  \phantom{-}0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
(We are a bit sloppy and identify the endomorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$ with the corresponding matrices with respect to our basis.) Thus the space of inner automorphisms is given by
$$
 I =
 \left\{
  \begin{pmatrix}
   c & d \\
   0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \,\middle|\,
  c,d \in K,
 \right\}
$$
where $K$ denotes the ground field. Let $D \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ be a dervation with
$$
 D =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  c_1 & c_2 \\
  c_3 & c_4
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Notice that
$$
 c_1 a + c_3 b
 = D(a)
 = D([a,b])
 = [D(a),b] + [a,D(b)]
 = c_1 a + c_4 b;
$$
comparing both sides gives $c_3 = c_4 =: c$. Now
$$
 D' := D - c_2 \mathrm{ad}_a + c_1 \mathrm{ad}_b
$$
is a derivation of $\mathfrak{g}$ with
$$
 D' =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  c & c
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Because
$$
 cb
 = D'(a)
 = D'([a,b])
 = [D'(a),b] + [a,D'(b)]
 = [cb,b] + [a,cb]
 = ca
$$
we find that $c = 0$. So $D$ is already of the form
$$
 D =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  c_1 & c_2 \\
  0   & 0
 \end{pmatrix},
$$
i.e. $D$ is an inner derivation.

Comment: Thanks Jendrik. How did you find $ad_a$ and $ad_b$ in this way? Also why $ad_a(b)=b$ ? I tried $ab-ba=b$ but how about $ad_a(b)$ in general?

Comment: (1) We know that $\mathrm{ad}_a(a) = [a,a] = 0$ and $\mathrm{ad}_a(b) = [a,b] = a$. So representing the endomorphism $\mathrm{ad}_a \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ with respect to the basis $(a,b)$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ gives the first matrix. In the same way we get the matrix representation of $\mathrm{ad}_b$. (2) I never claimed that $\mathrm{ad}_a(b) = b$. Instead I use that $\mathrm{ad}_a(b) = [a,b] = a$. The first equality follows from the definition of $\mathrm{ad}_a$ and the second from the Lie algebra structure on $\mathfrak{g}$, given in your original post.

Comment: (3) The commutator $[a,b]$ is _not_ given as $[a,b] = ab-ba$. We are dealing with an abstract Lie algebra, where $[-,-] \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is a bilinear alternating map satisfying the Jacobi identity. The expression $ab-ba$ does (a priori) not make sense, because the products $ab$ and $ba$ are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The result follows indeed by an explicit computation of all derivations of the $2$-dimensional. nonabelian Lie algebra, as demonstrated in the answer of Jendrik.
I think this is a perfect solution.

Later one could use more general results, by noting that this Lie algebra is the affine Lie algebra $\mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{R}^1)$, and using the well-known result that all affine Lie algebras $\mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are *complete*, i.e., have zero center and all derivations are *inner*.

Comment: It’s been some time since you’ve answered the question, but do you know a reference for the fact that all derivations of $\mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are inner?

Comment: @JendrikStelzner It is proved in a paper by Roger Carles from, say, $1984$ or so, on the cohomology of complete Lie algebras. I have to look up the exact reference.